# Apply na.fill to every column

Tags: r, na

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Col1    Col2     Col3     Col4    Col5   
   A       B        4        5       7
   G       H        5        6      NA
   H       I       NA        9       8
   K       F        9       NA      NA
   E       L       NA        8       9
   H       I        1        0      10
```

How do I apply the `na.fill()` function to all the columns after Col2?

If I were to do it individually, it would be something like this:

```
df$Col3<-na.fill(df$Col3, c(NA, "extend", NA))
df$Col4<-na.fill(df$Col4, c(NA, "extend", NA))
df$Col5<-na.fill(df$Col5, c(NA, "extend", NA))
```

The problem is that my actual dataframe has over 100 columns. Is there a quick way to apply this function to all the columns after the first 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`na.fill` *does* handle multiple columns.  Really no need to use `lapply`, `mutate`, etc.  Just replace the relevant columns with the result of running `na.fill` on those same columns.  If you know what `ix` is then you could replace the first line with it so that in this example we could alternately use `ix <- 3:5` or `ix <- -(1:2)` .

```
ix <- sapply(DF, is.numeric)
replace(DF, ix, na.fill(DF[ix], c(NA, "extend", NA)))
```

giving:

```
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
1    A    B    4  5.0  7.0
2    G    H    5  6.0  7.5
3    H    I    7  9.0  8.0
4    K    F    9  8.5  8.5
5    E    L    5  8.0  9.0
6    H    I    1  0.0 10.0
```

Note that you could alternately use `na.approx`:

```
replace(DF, ix, na.approx(DF[ix], na.rm = FALSE))
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "Col1    Col2     Col3     Col4    Col5   
   A       B        4        5       7
   G       H        5        6      NA
   H       I       NA        9       8
   K       F        9       NA      NA
   E       L       NA        8       9
   H       I        1        0      10"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `mutate_`-family of functions in the `dplyr` package would do the trick.

There are a few ways to do this. Some may work better than others depending on what your other columns look like. Here are three versions that would work better in different circumstances.

```
# Make dummy data.
df <- data.frame(
    Col1 = LETTERS[1:6],
    Col2 = LETTERS[7:12],
    Col3 = c(4, 5, NA, 9, NA, 1),
    Col4 = c(5,6,9,NA,8,0),
    Col5 = c(7,NA,8,NA,9,10)
)
```

You can apply the `na.fill` function to columns specified by name vector. This is useful if you want to use a regular expression to select columns with certain name parts.

```
cn <- names(df) %>%
    str_subset("[345]")    # Column names with 3, 4 or 5 in them.

result_1 <- df %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(cn),
        zoo::na.fill, c(NA, 'extend', NA)
        )
```

You can apply the `na.fill` function to any numeric column.

```
result_2 <- df %>%
    mutate_if(is.numeric,    # First argument is function that returns a logical vector.
        zoo::na.fill, c(NA, 'extend', NA)
        )
```

You can apply the function to columns specified in an numeric index vector.

```
result_3 <- df
result_3[ , 3:5] <- result_3[ , 3:5] %>%    # Just replace columns 3 through 5
    mutate_all(
        zoo::na.fill, c(NA, 'extend', NA)
        )
```

In this case, all three versions should have done the same thing.

```
all.equal(result_1, result_2)    # TRUE
all.equal(result_1, result_3)    # TRUE
```